# Once deployed my app reports - Cannot import name 'vision' from 'google.cloud'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am working on a Google App and have an issue when I deploy it. The project contains two services website and worker. The website acts as a front page and the worker is run through a cron and has its page hit every 5 minutes.

The issue I'm having is that when running them locally both services run fine. Once I deploy with gcloud the application returns an error in the Logs Console.

The error is: ImportError: cannot import name 'vision' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

It is the worker service that is not working. It's requirements.txt reads

```
Flask~=1.1.2
google-api-core==1.22.4
google-auth==1.23.0
google-cloud-core==1.4.3
google-cloud-datastore==2.0.0
google-cloud-logging==2.0.0
google-cloud-storage==1.33.0
google-cloud-vision==2.0.0
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.1.0
requests==2.25.0
```

The imports for the worker are

```
import os
import logging
import google.cloud.logging
import google.oauth2.id_token

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from google.auth.transport import requests
from google.cloud import datastore
from google.cloud import vision
```

The full error on the Logs explorer is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/layers/google.python.webserver/gunicorn/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/srv/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from google.cloud import vision
ImportError: cannot import name 'vision' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I've tried rearranging the imports as I read that there could be some namespace issues but that didn't fix it

Comment: I try to replicate this with the requirements file you shared, and it fails before reaching the vision import due to a missing rpcio module. If I include the rpcio module in requirements, then the imports succeeds. Based on this, I think of two options, 1st) that the requirements file shared here is not complete, that's why I wasn't able to replicate it; and 2nd) the instance is running out of memory causing the issue (I would try with a bigger instance here)

Comment: Thank you, including the grpcio module in the requirements.txt fixed this

Comment: Great! I included it as an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seemed to be caused by the order of the components in the requirements file, similar to [this issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6259). The solution is to explicitly include the `grpcio` module in the `requirements.txt` file, e.g. :

```
Flask~=1.1.2
google-api-core==1.22.4
google-auth==1.23.0
google-cloud-core==1.4.3
google-cloud-datastore==2.0.0
google-cloud-logging==2.0.0
google-cloud-storage==1.33.0
google-cloud-vision==2.0.0
google-crc32c==1.0.0
google-resumable-media==1.1.0
requests==2.25.0
grpcio==1.34.0
```